# One image that is cached for use across a site OR images for each spot in the site?

Tags: image, performance, caching, picturefill

Setting the stage, you're an ecommerce platform selling a product. That product's image exists in several places on the site as follows

- In a carousel about 150x150px
- On a quick view showing that product's image about 250x250
- On that product's page showing a thumbnail 80x80 of the product
- On that products's page showing full size of that image 300x300
- In the quick cart about 65x65
- In the full cart about 100x100

Would you serve 1 image that works in all of those spots and hope it is cached or would you serve each image exact size.

Given a few more situations, if a user has a cart full of items and leaves the site and comes back directly to their cart they have a large cart to load, or the user has left for a few days or weeks and there is a whole new set of products to see, so no more cached images.

What do you think is the most performant solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how many those sizes are shown on the same page. If all the sizes are on different pages then I would have different sizes and if they are all in the same page I would just load the biggest one.

In reality I would pick something in between. Not all the sizes but not only one size either. Something like combine the 150, 100, 80 and 65 to be 150. And the 250 and 300 to be 300.

Comment: That varies on 1 page there could be all of those images, but on another only about 2 of the sizes. Handling that would be very difficult.

Comment: True. would it make sense to optimized for the most visited pages then?